# Cómo cargar un TreeView sin ningún elemento seleccionado

Tags: python, gtk

Me encuentro haciendo pruebas con el GTK 3.0 y sus elementos.

Tengo un TreeView que carga un ListStore a partir de una lista.
Ahí va el código:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


# List de tuplas
# (el modelo de datos que rellenará el TreeView)
people = [("Bucky Roberts", 67, "Exotic Dancer"),
          ("Jenny Blue", 21, "Shepherd"),
          ("John Smith", 55, "Programmer"),
          ("Emma Anderson", 43, "Nurse"),
          ("Emily Wilson", 28, "Teacher")]


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__( self, title='Buscador de Personas' )
        #Esto da un relleno a la ventana principal
        self.set_border_width( 10 )
        #Esto da un tamaño por defecto a la ventana principal
        self.set_default_size( 200, 100 )

        # Layout
        layout = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(layout)

        '''
        En los TreeViews, se meten ListStores, NO Lists
        El TreeView, además de texto, puede contener, imágenes, barras de progreso (ProgressBar), ...
        '''

        # Convert data to ListStore (lists that TreeViews can display) and specify data types
        #   -> al constructor del ListStore se le pasan los tipos de los datos que tratará
        #   en cada una de sus columnas
        people_list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, int, str)
        for item in people:
            people_list_store.append(list(item))

        for row in people_list_store:
            print row[:],  # Print all data
            print(row[2])  # Print third column (profession)

        people_tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(people_list_store)


        for i, col_title in enumerate(["Name", "Age", "Profession"]):

            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()

            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(col_title, renderer, text=i)

            # Haciendo que las columnas se puedan ordenar y seleccionar
            #   -> Pulsar en la cabecera de cada columna para cambiar el orden (ASC|DESC)
            column.set_sort_column_id(i)

            # Columnas al TreeView
            people_tree_view.append_column(column)

        #Capturando la fila elegida
        selected_row = people_tree_view.get_selection()
        #Cada vez que se seleccione, se lanza el evento (o 'signal') llamado 'changed'
        #que llamará a la función 'item_selected'
        selected_row.connect("changed", self.item_selected)

        # Add al layout
        layout.pack_start(people_tree_view, True, True, 0)

    #Fila elegida de la lista
    def item_selected(self, selection):
        model, row = selection.get_selected()
        if row is not None:
            print("Name: ", model[row][0])
            print("Age: ", model[row][1])
            print("Job: ", model[row][2])
            print("")


#Creando el objeto ventana
window = MainWindow()

#Cuando el usuario pulse el icono para cerrar,
#se llamará al evento indicado para cerrar el programa
#y, por tanto, la ventana
window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

#Llamando al inicio del programa
Gtk.main()
```

Por defecto, el TreeView muestra seleccionado su primera fila.

He buscado y encontrado que alguno pone que sería así:

```
people_tree_view.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
```

Pero en la terminal me sale el mensaje de ERROR que el TreeView no tiene el método "set_mode()".

También, encontré que la forma de elegir un elemento determinado es:

```
people_tree_view.set_cursor(num_elem_a_elegir) #empezando por 0
```

He probado a pasar a ese cursor el "Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE" pero no lo acepta tampoco.

Entonces, ¿es posible cargar el TreeView sin ninguno de sus elementos seleccionado? ¿Cómo?

Estoy con Python 2.7 y GTK 3.0
Gracias y Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has probado que el foco inicie en otro elemento que no sea el TreeView?

Comment: Blasito, en el código, solo se muestra ese elemento en la pantalla. Por eso, no le podría dar el foco a otro elemento pues no hay otro. Aunque lo hubiera, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de no seleccionar por defecto un elemento del TreeView. Pero gracias, aún y todo, por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente el foco en el widget provoca de forma irremediable la llamada a `gtk_tree_view_focus_to_cursor` que va a terminar seleccionando la primera fila en el caso de no encontrar ninguna ya seleccionada.

Esto ocurre  con `gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE` pero no con el modo `gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE` y yo al menos no encuentro una forma directa de y "bonita" de resolverlo que no pase por "jugar" con el foco. Una posible idea es usar el evento `focus` para llamar a una callback que compruebe si se ha seleccionado previamente una fila y en caso contrario evite la propagación del evento:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


# List de tuplas
# (el modelo de datos que rellenará el TreeView)
people = [("Bucky Roberts", 67, "Exotic Dancer"),
          ("Jenny Blue", 21, "Shepherd"),
          ("John Smith", 55, "Programmer"),
          ("Emma Anderson", 43, "Nurse"),
          ("Emily Wilson", 28, "Teacher")]


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__( self, title='Buscador de Personas' )
        #Esto da un relleno a la ventana principal
        self.set_border_width( 10 )
        #Esto da un tamaño por defecto a la ventana principal
        self.set_default_size( 200, 100 )

        # Layout
        layout = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(layout)

        '''
        En los TreeViews, se meten ListStores, NO Lists
        El TreeView, además de texto, puede contener, imágenes, barras de progreso (ProgressBar), ...
        '''

        # Convert data to ListStore (lists that TreeViews can display) and specify data types
        #   -> al constructor del ListStore se le pasan los tipos de los datos que tratará
        #   en cada una de sus columnas
        people_list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, int, str)
        for item in people:
            people_list_store.append(list(item))

        for row in people_list_store:
            print(row[:])  # Print all data
            print(row[2])  # Print third column (profession)

        people_tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(people_list_store)


        for i, col_title in enumerate(["Name", "Age", "Profession"]):

            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()

            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(col_title, renderer, text=i)

            # Haciendo que las columnas se puedan ordenar y seleccionar
            #   -> Pulsar en la cabecera de cada columna para cambiar el orden (ASC|DESC)
            column.set_sort_column_id(i)

            # Columnas al TreeView
            people_tree_view.append_column(column)

        #Capturando la fila elegida
        self.selected_row = people_tree_view.get_selection()

        #Cada vez que se seleccione, se lanza el evento (o 'signal') llamado 'changed'
        #que llamará a la función 'item_selected'
        self.selected_row.connect("changed", self.item_selected)


        # Add al layout
        layout.pack_start(people_tree_view, True, True, 0)          
        people_tree_view.connect("focus", self.on_focus)



    #Fila elegida de la lista
    def item_selected(self, selection):
        model, row = selection.get_selected()
        if row is not None:
            self._focus_selection = False
            print("Name: ", model[row][0])
            print("Age: ", model[row][1])
            print("Job: ", model[row][2])
            print("")

    def on_focus(self, *args):
        model, row = self.selected_row.get_selected()
        if row is  None:
            return True  # Bloqueamos la propagación del evento 




#Creando el objeto ventana
window = MainWindow()

#Cuando el usuario pulse el icono para cerrar,
#se llamará al evento indicado para cerrar el programa
#y, por tanto, la ventana
window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

#Llamando al inicio del programa
Gtk.main()
```

Me sigue pareciendo un poco *hack* la solución, pero por ahora es lo mejor que se me ocurre que evite este comportamiento ante la asignación del foco en el widget por cualquier mecanismo.

Comment: Probada, aceptada y almacenada la proposición para cuando vuelva con el Gtk. :) ... Ahora, que me he pasado del Sublime al VSCode, al probar a ejecutar este código y otros con Gtk desde el editor con CTRL+B, me acabo de dar cuenta de que la ventana se queda en segundo plano, lo que no me pasa con el Sublime ... estoy con esa tontería que tendré que dejar para no pasar el tiempo :) ... Saludos.

Comment: Me añado en este comentario para otras posibles problemáticas de foco el enlace a esta **[pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450180/change-the-focus-from-one-text-widget-to-another)** en la que se habla de pasar el foco al siguiente elemento desde un Text de Tkinter. ¡Interesante!

Answer (score 1):

¿Tu ventana tendrá únicamente un TreeView dentro un Box? En caso de respuesta negativa, acá una solución poco elegante:

Si no quieres que el foco vaya directamente al TreeView, **añadir primero cualquier otro widget al Box** soluciona el problema.

Por ejemplo, añadiendo primero un Button al Box.

[image: Añadiendo primero un Button al Box]